# How to create a generic use library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, activex

I have an image editor user control(c# .net v2.0). Its used in thousands of computers as an activex component. I want the component also be available for windows forms and possible other uses.

For activex usage i add `<object>` tag in html code and call the component with clsid(a static guid). So if i build and distribute a newer version it works without changing any client code.

I want windows forms to be able use the same distributed libraries. And they should not reference a specific version so i can update the component without changing the programs that use it.

I use regasm to register for com. But i dont know how to reference it from visual studio(like referencing with clsid?)

May be in visual stuido when i choose add reference and select COM tab i shuld see my component in the list.

note: i tried to add the assemly to the global cache using these lines but it did not work out-or i coulnt understand if anything has changed :)

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\tlbexp" ImageEditorComp.dll /out:ImageEditorComp.tlb
regasm /tlb:ImageEditorComp.tlb ImageEditorComp.dll
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\gacutil" /I ImageEditorComp.dll
```

Any suggestions appreciated,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

To explain step by step:

1- Create the component with all needed properties for com.(Sign the assembly, use interfaces for com, make assembly com visible)

On the client machine

2- Register the assembly with regasm(i recommend adding safety flags too).

3- Add the assembly to the global cache using gacutil(or msi installer)

I figured out when you call a specific version of an assembly gac is searched in the first place so if its installed in GAC, referenced codebase path is never used.

When using as activeX you address the component with GUID. Since regasm adds the assembly name and version the GUID is representing, web browser directly uses component from GAC.

When using from a desktop application, reference the assebmly directly and set copylocal property to false. Similarly, in the client machine windows will find the assembly located at GAC itself.

Here is a useful link about the subject.

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-.net-com-assembly/

Hope it saves other peoples time :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, you'll invoke the infamous and dreaded DLL Hell problem.  A stone cold hard rule in COM is that you *have* to change the [Guid] attribute values on public interfaces when you make a breaking change in either the publicly visible interfaces or the implementation of them.  Changing the guids ensures that you don't overwrite the registry keys of an old version of your component when you use Regasm.exe.  Existing programs that use your component and were not recompiled to use the latest version will continue running without problems.  The typical outcome of DLL Hell is a nasty hardware exception like AccessViolation, *very* difficult to troubleshoot.

None of which applies in your specific case here.  There is no point in trying to use the component through COM.  It is a .NET assembly, just add the reference to it directly.  The IDE will in fact stop you from adding a reference to the interop library.  But not the .tlb.  The GAC keeps you out of DLL Hell, assuming you properly increment [AssemblyVersion].

Comment: Thanks for the answer it my saved time to figure out the solution.